# How do I view the full file path in the title bar when I search for something in file explorer?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

What I mean is if I search for something in file explorer and then go to that location, at the top it displays the path as "Search result in folder" instead of "C/.../folder". Here is what I mean:

Searching for the folder:

[image: Searching for the folder]

Selecting the folder I want:

[image: Selecting the folder I want]

This is what it displays:

[image: This is what it displays]

This is what I want:

[image: This is what I want]

Comment: When I search in Windows 10 from File Explorer, top right search bar, any files found show the complete path. I cannot tell from your post what is not working except to say it all works fine.  The Title Bar does not change though, just the results.

Comment: If you press Ctrl+Shift, right-click a file or folder, and select *Copy as path*, the full path (escaped in quotes) is copied to the clipboard. This works for files in a location alias such as *Desktop*, *Downloads*, *Music*, etc. For a link (shortcut), though, it copies the location of the .lnk file; if you want the indirect location, it's in the link's Properties.

Comment: You can find the setting in Control Panel>File explorer options>view>Display the full path in title bar, tick the box and hit apply.

Answer (score 0):

I created a context menu entry for folders, `Open file-system location` to deal with this and similar virtual paths (i.e. `This PC >`*`<FolderName>)`*:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\OpenLocation]
@="&Open file-system location"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\OpenLocation\command]
@="\"explorer.exe\" \"%v\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\OpenLocation]
@="&Open file-system location"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\OpenLocation\command]
@="\"explorer.exe\" \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\OpenLocation]
@="&Open File Location"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\OpenLocation\command]
@="\"explorer.exe\" /select,\"%1\""
```

It does open a new window, rather than use the open window, but that's a minor trade-off in my opinion.

Comment: I have it set up and can click the "OpenLocation" button, but whenever I do I get the error message "windows cannot access the specified device path or file you may not have appropriate permissions to access the item".

Comment: Is that a new Explorer window that displays the error message???